# How do you use the pdf-forms gem to form-fill a PDF with images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-form

I'm trying to put together several different pieces, and I'm not sure if it's even possible.

- I know you can use the pdf-forms gem to form-fill a PDF in Ruby on Rails.
- I know it's possible to create a form-fillable PDF with adobe acrobat.
- I know it's possible to upload images into adobe acrobat form-fillable PDFs -- I've seen several forms that do this.

I'm trying to figure out how to line the pieces up so users can upload images, which are then (programmatically) form-filled into the PDF.